# TDD with python

Tags: python, pytest

I need a little help guys, I'm doing a project for school and i'm running in to an issue with my code. Not sure where i'm going wrong. Here is a little bit about the project.

Requirements:
Write a function called generate_prime_factors in the module prime.py. This function will accept an integer as an argument, and return a list of integers.

Step 1:
Write a test that asserts that when generate_prime_factors is called with a data type that is not an integer (e.g. a string or float), a ValueError is raised. Write the appropriate code to solve this and then commit the changes.

Step 2:
Write a test that asserts that when generate_prime_factors is called with 1, an empty list is returned. Solve & commit.

Step 3:
Write a test that asserts that when generate_prime_factors is called with 2, the list [2] is returned. Solve & commit.

etc.....

this is my main prime.py:

```
    """
    generate prime factors fuctions
    """
    if user_input == 1:
        return prime_factors
    if user_input == 2:
        return prime_factors
    if isinstance(user_input, str):
        raise ValueError
    return prime_factors
```

and here is my test python script:

```
import pytest
from prime import generate_prime_factors # Imports the prime module (prime.py)

def test_not_integer():
    """
    A test that asserts that when `generate_prime_factors` is called with a
    data type that is not an integer (e.g. a string or float), a ValueError is
    raised.
    """
    prime_factors = []
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        generate_prime_factors('Hello World', prime_factors)

def test_generate_prime_factor_1():
    """
    A test that asserts that when `generate_prime_factors` is called with
    `1`, an empty list is returned.
    """
    prime_factors = []
    generate_prime_factors(1, prime_factors)
    assert prime_factors == []

def test_generate_prime_factor_2():
    """
    a test that asserts that when `generate_prime_factors` is called with
    `2`, the list `[2]` is returned.
    """
    prime_factors = []
    generate_prime_factors(2, prime_factors)
    assert prime_factors == [2]
```

[image]

as you can see from the image. I keep getting pytest error, seems to be coming from the def test_generate_prime_factors_2(): method as you can see from the image two pass and 1 fail

Comment: please, clearly state what problem you would like to have help on.

Comment: sorry I keep getting pytest error in the image. seems to be coming from the def test_generate_prime_factors_2(): method as you can see from the image two pass and 1 fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function, you're returning prime_factors.

But in your test, you're not using that return value.

Your prime_factor value in your test is never assigned, so it remains an empty list.

Comment: I'm new to python i thought that's what I was doing when i wrote ```assert prime_factors == [2] ``` Could you give me a little bit more info?

Comment: This works but could you verify if i'm on the right track? 
```if user_input == 2:
        return [2]```
in my test i have this:
```def test_generate_prime_factor_2():
    prime_factors = []
    assert generate_prime_factors(2, prime_factors) == [2]```

Comment: those would be questions better suited for your teacher. You might want to ask more precise questions here. Did my answer above answer your initial question?

Comment: Yes.. Thanks I think i'm on the write track.. I did put in a question to my teacher to see if he wants me to write the algorithm to calculate the prime in the main prime.py or just a simple if statement.